# Configuring a SonarQube webservice

Tags: java, sonarqube5.1

I've created a custom SonarQube webservice by implementing `org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService` and would like to pass some server specific configuration to it.

For other plugins I access a Settings object from the context, but `org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService.Context` doesn't provide one.

How are webservices meant to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be trivial - just inject the Settings object as a dependency via the constructor.